# How to build (generic) Endpoint controller class (hierachy)

Tags: scala, google-app-engine, generics, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I’d like to create a couple of Endpoint controller classes (using Objectify), and since they share a lot of common code, use some generic base class.
I thought of doing something like this:

```
@Api(
  backendRoot = "http://localhost:8888/_ah/spi",
  root = "http://localhost:8888/_ah/api",
  version = "v1"
)
abstract class BaseController[T <: Entity[T]] {

  protected def getApiClass() : Class[T]

  @ApiMethod(
    name = "read",
    path = "read",
    httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET
  )
  def read() : JList[T] =   {
    OfyS.ofy().load().`type`(getApiClass()).list().asInstanceOf[JList[T]]
  }  

  def create(entity : T) : T =  {
  …
  }
…
}
```

and

```
@Api(
  name = "misc"
)
class MiscController extends BaseController[Misc] {
    override protected def getApiClass() = classOf[Misc]
}
```

as one of several implementations. This way, I’d basically only have to replace the type and API name in each implementation (this is the basic idea).

Alas, Endpoints tries to expose getApiClass() to the API and I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameterized type java.lang.Class<Misc> not supported
```

(afaik, I cannot omit the type parameterization in here.)

This happens although the method is protected and the docs state that only public methods are exposed. This might well be because the Scala flavor of ‘protected’ (I simply don’t know). If it is private (which basically works if I’m not using a class hierarchy), I cannot override it.

Do you have any clues on how to make the basic idea work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question! Here's how I solve this problem...

Each of my **Endpoint**s look like this:

**WARNING: This is not production-ready code! (In particular, notice I don't use Cursor. I couldn't because of a different problem I faced).**

```
public class MyEndpoint {
@ApiMethod(
    name = "get",
    path = "bean/{id}",
    httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public Bean get(@Named("id") Long id) throws NotFoundException {
    return new MyService().get(id);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, lets look at **MyService** class:

```
public class MyService extends AbstractService<Long, Bean> {
    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(Bean.class);
    }
    public MyService() {
        super(Long.class, Bean.class);
    }
}
```

And, finally, **AbstractService**:

```
    public class AbstractService<D, T> {
        protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AbstractService.class.getName());
        private final Class<?> idClazz;
        private final Class<? extends T> clazz;
        public AbstractService(Class<?> idClazz, Class<? extends T> clazz) {
            this.idClazz = idClazz;
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

public T get(D id) throws NotFoundException {
            logger.info("Getting " + clazz.getName() + " with ID: " + id);
            T obj = null;
            if (idClazz == Long.class) {
                Long parsedId = (Long) id;
                obj = ofy().load().type(clazz).id(parsedId).now();
            } else if (idClazz == String.class) {
                String parsedId = (String) id;
                obj = ofy().load().type(clazz).id(parsedId).now();
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                throw new NotFoundException("Could not find " + getClass().getName() + " with ID: " + id);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public T insert(T obj) {
            ofy().save().entity(obj).now();
            logger.info("Created " + clazz.getName() + ".");
            return ofy().load().entity(obj).now();
        }

        public T update(D id, T obj) throws NotFoundException {
            checkExists(id);
            ofy().save().entity(obj).now();
            logger.info("Updated " + clazz.getName() + ": " + obj);
            return ofy().load().entity(obj).now();
        }

        public void remove(D id) throws NotFoundException {
            checkExists(id);
            T obj = null;
            if (idClazz == Long.class) {
                Long parsedId = (Long) id;
                ofy().delete().type(clazz).id(parsedId).now();
            } else if (idClazz == String.class) {
                String parsedId = (String) id;
                ofy().delete().type(clazz).id(parsedId).now();
            }
            logger.info("Deleted " + getClass().getName() + " with ID: " + id);
        }

        public CollectionResponse<T> list() {
            //        limit = limit == null ? DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT : limit;
            logger.info("Listing " + clazz.getName() + "s");
            Query<? extends T> query = ofy().load().type(clazz);
            QueryResultIterator<? extends T> queryIterator = query.iterator();
            List<T> objList = new ArrayList<T>();
            while (queryIterator.hasNext()) {
                objList.add(queryIterator.next());
            }
            return CollectionResponse.<T>builder().setItems(objList).build();
        }

        public CollectionResponse<T> list(int limit, int startAt) {
            logger.info("Listing " + clazz.getName() + "s");
            Query<? extends T> query = ofy().load().type(clazz).offset(startAt).limit(limit);
            QueryResultIterator<? extends T> queryIterator = query.iterator();
            List<T> objList = new ArrayList<T>();
            while (queryIterator.hasNext()) {
                objList.add(queryIterator.next());
            }
            return CollectionResponse.<T>builder().setItems(objList).build();
        }

        private void checkExists(D id) throws NotFoundException {
            try {
                if (idClazz == Long.class) {
                    Long parsedId = (Long) id;
                    ofy().load().type(clazz).id(parsedId).safe();
                } else if (idClazz == String.class) {
                    String parsedId = (String) id;
                    ofy().load().type(clazz).id(parsedId).safe();
                }
            } catch (com.googlecode.objectify.NotFoundException e) {
                throw new NotFoundException("Could not find " + getClass().getName() + " with ID: " + id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course! How could I be so blind to forget about the constructor.. Thanks!